# file does not exist when upload image from tablet camera

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

i'am trying to upload image from tablet camera but when submit [image: this error displayed]
this is my html code

```
 <form action="/add_transaction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Image</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-3">
                       <input type="file" name="image">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

and this is my laravel code :

```
$new_transaction = new Transaction;
    $new_transaction->image_path = $request->image->store('public/transaction_images');
    $new_transaction->save();
```

any help please :(

Comment: How is the form submitted? You can also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169126/laravel-not-storing-files-from-request) to see if you find any clues.

Comment: sorry i forget put the submit button

Comment: Debug it. Put `dd($new_transaction);` before save line and also check if file is uploaded. What do you mean with this "from tablet camera"? Does upload work when you just select image for upload regardless of camera?

Comment: this error occurred only when upload from camera .. but when upload from gallery uploaded successfully

Comment: the problem is occurred because path is wrong ????

Comment: This might be because uploaded camera pictures have no path name (hence the ""), so maybe you need to save the image with a name?

Comment: you mean  .. store the image and upload it ?